# RecyclerView doesn't add EditText until second time it's clicked? (notifyDataSetChanged?)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

**Goal: Use RecyclerView to add EditText fields to Activity**

What's happening: I would like for LinearLayouts(horizontal) with ImageView and EditText to be added to the screen whenever the "Add" button is clicked. They are not showing up until I:

-1)Type in the edittext field and click done

-2) Click add

-3) Click on the EditText field I already typed in and then click done again, or click off of it

It SHOULD add after Step 2, not Step 3. My thought is it has something to do with the notifyDataSetChanged but I'm not sure what?

Research done: Spent the last few days going through documentation, tutorials, youtube videos, and stackoverflow searches

Testing done: Tried moving placement of my method that calls notifyDataSetChanged();
Tried changing the dimensions of the layout
Tried changing the inputType

MyAdapter.java:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>{
    private ArrayList<LinearLayout> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;
    private Random mRandom = new Random();


    public MyAdapter(Context context){

        mContext = context;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public EditText mTextEditName, mTextEditLocation;
        public LinearLayout mRelativeLayout; //from the (Main)Activity XML
        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);
            mTextEditName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.nameOfBusinessET);

            mRelativeLayout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.rl);
        }
    }

    void updateDataSet(ArrayList<LinearLayout> myArrayList) {
        mDataSet = myArrayList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        // Create a new View
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.mTextEditName.setText("");

    }       

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

RegisterBusinessActivity.java:

```
public class RegisterBusinessActivity extends Activity {

    EditText businessLocationET;

    //FIREBASE ITEMS
    private static FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private static final String TAG = "RealtimeDB";
    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference dbRef;
    private EditText businessName;

    //RECYCLERVIEW ITEMS
    private Context mContext;
    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    int position;
    ArrayList<LinearLayout> linearLayoutList = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_businessprofile);

        Button addLocationBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addLocationBtn);
        businessLocationET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.businessLocationET);


        // Get the widgets reference from XML layout
        mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mContext = getApplicationContext(); // Get the application context
        linearLayoutList.add(mLinearLayout);

        // Define a layout for RecyclerView
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        // Initialize a new instance of RecyclerView Adapter instance
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext);

        // Set the adapter for RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.updateDataSet(linearLayoutList);


        //FIREBASE FIELDS
        businessName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameOfBusinessET);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbRef = database.getReference("/data");
        currentUser =
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();            



        //ADD EXTRA LOCATIONS
        addLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                linearLayoutList.add(mLinearLayout);
            }
        });


    DatabaseReference.CompletionListener completionListener =
            new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,
                                       DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                    if (databaseError != null) {
                        notifyUser(databaseError.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            };


    private void notifyUser(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(RegisterBusinessActivity.this, message,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you don't update your recycler after the 'add' click event. You just add item to the list without to update the adapter/recyclerview.

One option is just to use specific position you added:

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(yourItems.size() - 1);
```

or better than using:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So it will look like that:

```
addLocationBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                linearLayoutList.add(mLinearLayout);
                mAdapter.updateDataSet(linearLayoutList);
            }
 });
```

Comment: Hi motis10:    I have mAdapter.updateDataSet(linearLayoutList) in my RegisterBusinessActivity.java .... are you saying to ALSO add it to the onClick as well? or JUST in the onClick?

Comment: So its adding them, but the ordering is Odd. I type 'test1' into the first, then click Add. I type 'test2' into the second, then click Add. The third one goes above 1 and 2, so when I type 'test3' into it it shows from top to bottom as test3, test1, test2